# Bokeh : use of rectangles glyph, width and x sharing

Tags: bokeh, rectangles

I am using Bokeh (1.4.0) in python for interactive plotting. I am using a rectangle plot as an anomaly alerting feedback on data. Unfortunately there are enormous white gaps between the rectangles. The width parameter does not change anything. This is probably due to the x_sharing parameter with the first plot I above.

```
plot_options = dict(plot_width=width, plot_height=300, x_axis_type="datetime",
                            x_range=p1.x_range)
p4 = figure(title="Analyse d'anomalie", tools="reset, pan, box_select, wheel_zoom", y_range=tuple(anomaly_names), **plot_options)
        for j,name in list(zip(range(len(anomaly_names)), anomaly_names)):
            p4.rect(x="estampilles", y=heatmap_y_coordinate[j], width=1000, height=1, line_color=None,
            line_alpha=0, fill_color=transform(name, mapper), dilate=True, source=source_dic)
```

Here `source_dic` is a dictionary.

[The third plot from the top shows narrow rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvRRc.png)

Has anyone any idea on how to tackle this ? There is nothing written on the documentation about this. I am eager to hear from the community.

Thanks.

Yours,

G.H

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, the way to solve this is to use datetime.timedelta(minutes=15) for example to have automatic adjusting rectangles.

G.H.